# Create a visual in power BI with column name and values in 2 different columns as shown in the screenshot

Tags: powerbi

I want to create a visual in Power BI with column names in one column and corresponding values in the other column. I have attached as screenshot below for clarity.

[image: table like visual]

I tried to use multi-row card but does not do the job. any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the Matrix visual.

- Add your columns to the `Values` well
- Then under `Format visual` properties `Values` section > `Options` - Turn on `Switch values to row groups rather than columns`

You will something similar to:
[image]
Then you can rename the Values, do a little formatting on the `Row Headers` etc...

---

An alternative is to use the "HTML Content (lite)" custom visual available in the AppSource. With it you can create a measure of the HTML you want to present.  Example measure to be used with the visual:

```
HtmlTable = "
<table>
  <tr><td>School ID</td><td>"& FIRSTNONBLANK('School'[School ID], 1) &"</td></tr>
  <tr><td>School Name</td><td>"& FIRSTNONBLANK('School'[School Name], 1) &"</td></tr>
</table>
"
```

Comment: It is what I wanted (used the Matrix option), works as I expected. Thanks heaps.